# transferring header names for matrix columns in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix A with N columns, and I take 2 (or any subset) of columns from this matrix to construct a new matrix B, for instance:

```
B = cbind(A[,1], A[,3])
```

Is there a simple argument I can add so that the header name for the two columns is transferred? Using `names(B) = names(A)` won't work because the matrices are not the same dimension.

Comment: you will slecet how the columns? by name?

Comment: For instance, I use B=cbind(A[,1],A[,3]), to construct matrix B which is just columns 1 and 3 from A.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that it was an expected courtesy, and will do so in the future.

Comment: No problem, that's why we said something. You can also go back and accept answers on your old questions too (but of course, only do that if an answer actually solved your problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example would help greatly since I suspect you may be using a dataframe which you are incorrectly calling a matrix. I say that because the names<- function used with a matrix would destroy the matrix structure. The proper function to modify column names is `colnames<-`. Furthermore if you were extracting the columns from a matrix using the "[" function there is almost no way the the column names would not come across with the values:

```
> mat <- matrix(1:9, 3)
> colnames(mat) <- letters[1:3]
> mat[ , 2:3]
     b c
[1,] 4 7
[2,] 5 8
[3,] 6 9
```

Responding to your comment, it would be better to do this:

```
B <- A[ , c(1,3) ]
```

Then your column names would be properly carried over. (Note added: I was surprised that your cbind operation did not bring the col.names over and wondered why that was so. This version of using "[" with cbind does retain the col.names:

```
> B=cbind( A[,1,drop=FALSE], A[,3,drop=FALSE])
> B
     a c
[1,] 1 7
[2,] 2 8
[3,] 3 9
```

The "[" function will coerce single columns or rows to an atomic vector and apparently also looses its dimnames attribute. `drop=FALSE` prevents that loss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subset with 'select' `?subset`

```
 B <- subset(A,select = c(col1,col2))
```

e.g

```
 A <- mtcars
 B <- subset(A,select = c(mpg,cyl))

                      mpg cyl
Mazda RX4         21.0   6
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6
Datsun 710        22.8   4
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8
Valiant           18.1   6
```

if you do by index :

```
      B=cbind(A[,1],A[,3])
      colnames(B) <- colnames(A)[c(1,3)]
```